# Passing JSON from Model to Route is not working

Tags: json, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to pass an object from a model to my route so I can finish my login system but I'm not recieving anything.

Model code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const config = require('../config/config.json');
var dynamoose = require('dynamoose');
const express = require('express');
var Schema = dynamoose.Schema;

const USER_SCHEMA = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  credential: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

const USER = module.exports = dynamoose.model('Usuarios', USER_SCHEMA);

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function (user, callback) {
  var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  var params = {
    TableName: "Users",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#us = :uuuu",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#us": "username"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":uuuu": user
    }
  };
  docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
      data.Items.forEach(function (user, callback) {
        console.log(user.username + ": " + user.password + user.email + user.firstName);
      });
    }
    callback(null, user);
  });
}
```

This is working fine, I can print user.username, user.password and so on, but for some reason my router is not importing the JSON

```
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;


  USER.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({
        success: false,
        "msg": "User not found"
      });
    }
    USER.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (isMatch) {
        const token = jwt.sign({
          username: user
        }, secret.secret, {
          expiresIn: 86400
        });

        res.json({
          success: true,
          token: 'JWT ' + token,
          user: {
            user: user.username,
            password: USER.password,
            email: user.email
          }
        });
      } else {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          msg: 'Wrong password'
        })
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The res.json from comparePassword should be the object from the route (which is the user model) but is not recieving a thing. I have tried with USER.username/email/etc user.username/email/etc but nothing works. I know I must be missing something somewhere, but where?

This is the response from the res.json

```
{
    "success": true,
    "token": "JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im5pY29sYXMuZ2FyY2lhIiwiaWF0IjoxNTA5ODE5NjMxLCJleHAiOjE1MDk5MDYwMzF9.ubHbqwOZznoeR0C-FkUoX83MoYPomk5SW1ThIA7ww74",
    "user": {}
}
```

The empty user should be, of course, the user object

---

### Fix:

First, I was using a `forEach`, so I had to pass an index (`user.Item[0].username`) and then I found that I can query just 1 item with Dynamo DB using a simple `.get` function.

Model now:

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function (user, callback) {
  var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  var params = {
    TableName: 'Users',
    Key: {
      "username": user
    }
  };

  docClient.get(params, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
      callback(null, user);
    }
  });
}
```

And by the way, Dynamo DB return items as Item, so my route now:

```
USER.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (isMatch) {
        const token = jwt.sign({
          username: user
        }, secret.secret, {
          expiresIn: 86400
        });
        res.json({
          success: true,
          token: 'JWT ' + token,
          user: {
            user: user.Item.username,
            password: user.Item.password,
            email: user.Item.email,
            firstName: user.Item.firstName,
            lastName: user.Item.lastName,
            credential: user.Item.credential
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: `USER.password` should be `user.password`?

Comment: No. That works fine because I'm passing the username and password through postman and express is parsing that information, but email is the problem.

Comment: can you confirm that the "user.username", "password: USER.password" and user.email are not empty in the json and your expressjs version?

Comment: I found the error, I'm returning the object from a forEach, I need to pass an index.

Answer (score 0):

I also think you will have to change your comparePassword to match below changes

```
//change comparePassword
USER.comparePassword(password, user, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (isMatch) {
        const token = jwt.sign({
          username: user
        }, secret.secret, {
          expiresIn: 86400
        });

        res.json({
          success: true,
          token: 'JWT ' + token,
          user: {
            user: user.username,
            password: user.password,
            email: user.email
          }
        });
      } else {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          msg: 'Wrong password'
        })
      }
    });
```

Comment: Response: 
{
    "success": true,
    "token": "JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6eyJJdGVtcyI6W3siY3JlZGVudGlhbCI6ImFkbWluIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiIkMmEkMTAkNGNyOFN0TWZHTURCRG91RDJOMGJOZTh0MkczZWI5VDlhc1g2eW43M1doNm9xRlJyMldPTmkiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im5pY29sYXMuZ2FyY2lhIiwiZW1haWwiOiJuaWNvbGFzZWNhbWlsb0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiJOaWNvbMOhcyIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiR2FyY8OtYSJ9XSwiQ291bnQiOjEsIlNjYW5uZWRDb3VudCI6MX0sImlhdCI6MTUwOTgyMDc3MywiZXhwIjoxNTA5OTA3MTczfQ.mSUYlqXFMoJUhaxlKV12ypioOppbzWm0HeLEfR1XTJw",
    "user": {}
}


Empty user :(

Answer (score 0):

When you return your user object in your callback it isn't in scope...

```
  docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
      data.Items.forEach(function (user, callback) {
        // user exists in this scope
        console.log(user.username + ": " + user.password + user.email + user.firstName);
        // something like...
        if(user) return callback(null, user)
      });
    }
    // user is undefined here
    // callback(null, user);
  });
```